# I don't understand the Feynman path integral!

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral

Let's say that in 2D space, in a vacuum, there is a point A and a point B. A particle x travels from point A to B.

I've heard people say, that in this case, probabilistically, the particle will travel in a straight line between these points. Fair enough.
But what if we add a stationary second particle, y?

This is my question: would the particle still favour travelling in a straight line?

What if particle x isn't angled towards point B when it begins it's journey, and instead bounces off particle y to get to B? The way I see it, neither that path or the straight line path are more favorable than the other, it's just that one requires more energy, and I don't understand why that would necessarily mean that it's less likely.

(please remember that this is all hypothetical)[image]

Comment: Forget the second particle. The Feynman path integral approach says that the first particle takes *all possible paths* between A and B, not the straight line. The integral adds up the contribution of each path to the probability amplitude. Before you can understand how the straight line is still relevant in quantum mechanics, you have to understand that all paths are possible and all contribute to the amplitude. And it’s not that it *might* take *any* path; it *does* take *all* paths. Conceptually, quantum mechanics is about as different from classical mechanics as is possible to imagine!

Comment: @G.Smith one thing I would like to point out is the paths are not observable so it doesn't make sense which path did the particle take to reach the destination. And whenever I have used this formalise the only quantity of interest was propagator and not the **paths** they never entered in the calculation and when we do perturbation the path intgeration never appears since we use only $Z[J]$ and it's derivative.

Comment: @aitfel The path integral is what *produces* the propagator and gives it a simple and revealing interpretation.

Comment: I understand that a particle takes all possible paths, but each path has a certain probability. By my understanding, it is known that the most probable, in the case I provided, is a straight line (as I explained). I don't see why adding a second particle is a problem.

Comment: No, each path does *not* have a probability. Each path has a probability *amplitude*, which is a *complex* number. You add up the amplitudes of every path and *then* take the square of the magnitude as the probability.

Comment: If the two particles have some kind of interaction, then the straight line will not be the classical path and will not dominate the path integral.

Comment: Is this statement true (I've heard a lot of people say it): the most probable path of a particle (calculated by the path integral) is the most likely path for the particle to take when observed.

Comment: No. Each path contributes a complex number, $e^{iS/\hbar}$, with exactly the same magnitude, 1. The contributions differ only in *phase*. What happens is that the phases make the contributions of paths quite different from the straight line cancel each other, leaving the contribution from the straight line and nearby paths to dominate.

Comment: You do not observe the path at all. You observe that the particle was at A and is now at B. All you observe is the endpoints. It does not *have* “a path that it took”.

Comment: If it had a path, you would know its position and momentum at each instant. But the uncertainty principle forbids this.

Comment: When you say probability, the probability of what?

Comment: In the context of this question, “probability” means the probability that a particle observed at one point A in spacetime is later observed at another point B in spacetime. The probability that it “propagates” from A to B... somehow. *Not* via any particular trajectory, which a quantum particle cannot have.